# How to get data from all matching elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following elements:

```
<div data-id="1">firstElement</div>
<div data-id="2">secondElement</div>
<div data-id="3">thirdElement</div>
```

I know I could select all the elements with:

```
$('[data-id]')

Or .filter Or .find Or querySellectorAll
```

Or even implement a function on them:

```
$('[data-id]').each
```

But I don't know how to get the values not the elements.

I want to gather them inside an array , So that the final result is:

```
['1', '2' ,'3'] OR [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I’m jQuery you can access data attributes with ‘.data()’ method. ~ $(‘div’).each((i, obj) => {$(this).data(‘id’);}

Comment: With data() you write whatever is after the dash

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by iterating over `$('[data-id]')`

```js
var values = [];
$('[data-id]').each(function(){
  values.push($(this).data('id'))
})
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="1">firstElement</div>
<div data-id="2">secondElement</div>
<div data-id="3">thirdElement</div>
```

Comment: Why using `const`? Force to use a transpiler just for that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the JavaScript native functions & works faster then jQuery:

```
var dataValues = [];
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id]').forEach(function(ele){
  // You can add if condition to check the value base on your logic
  // if (condition is true) {
     dataValues.push(Number(ele.getAttribute('data-id')));
  // }
})
console.log(dataValues);
```

See the live example below:

```js
var dataValues = [];
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id]').forEach(function(ele){
  // You can add if condition to check the value base on your logic
  // if (condition is true) {
     dataValues.push(Number(ele.getAttribute('data-id')));
  // }
})
console.log(dataValues);
```

```html
<div data-id="1">firstElement</div>
<div data-id="2">secondElement</div>
<div data-id="3">thirdElement</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.data method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) from jQuery for this!

So you could do the following, specifically to get an array out of what you have:

```js
var arr = [];
$('[data-id]').each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).data('id'));
});

console.log(arr);  // [1, 2, 3]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="1">firstElement</div>
<div data-id="2">secondElement</div>
<div data-id="3">thirdElement</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new list from an existing list so you can use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function to iterate through your list and returns a new list of only the desires items/elements of your original list.

You can achieve that by:

```
$.map($('div[data-id]'), x => $(x).data('id'))
```